# Getting GBs of PHP warnings on my error_log

Tags: php, wordpress

The lines of code that gives me errors are:

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
        $conteudo .= fread($handle, 1024);
    }
```

The error is:

```
[14-Jul-2016 16:39:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/brazpayc/public_html/wp-content/themes/brazpay/page-42.php on line 118
[14-Jul-2016 16:39:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/brazpayc/public_html/wp-content/themes/brazpay/page-42.php on line 119
```

I don't know if this is enough info, I hope someone could help me.

```
    <?php 

$brazpay = get_template_directory();
$brazpay_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

  if (isset($_GET['n'])) {
    $n = intval($_GET['load']);
    $l = explode(",", $_GET['ld']);

    brazpay_posts($n, $l);
  }

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {

  $user_name = $_GET['username'];
  $user_cpf = $_GET['usercpf'];
  $user_cnjp = $_GET['usercnjp'];
  $user_street = $_GET['userlocat'];
  $user_number = $_GET['usernumber'];
  $user_complement = $_GET['usercomplement'];
  $user_district = $_GET['userbarrio'];
  $user_state = $_GET['userstate'];
  $user_city = $_GET['usercity'];
  $user_postcode = $_GET['usercep'];
  $user_country = (int)$_GET['usercountry'];
  $user_value = (int)$_GET['uservalue'];

  if ($user_cpf != '' && $user_cnjp == ''){
    $user_code = "<cpf>$user_cpf</cpf>";
  } elseif ($user_cnjp != '' && $user_cpf == '') {
    $user_code = "<cnjp>$user_cnjp</cnjp>";
  } else {
    die("Fatal error cpf $user_cpf and cnjp $user_cnjp");
  }

$URL = "http://boleto.msbbank.com.br/boleto.php"; 
$n_website = '20468565324-1'; //identificador único adquirido para acesso ao sistema – unique website ID 
$password = '1e$ha!.'; //senha adquirida para acesso ao sistema - password 
$uid = uniqid(); //identificador único da transação no website – unique transaction ID 
$name = $user_name; //'Daniel Rodrigues'; //nome do sacado – buyer’s name 
$identificador = $user_cpf; //'11091866732'; //CPF do sacado – buyer’s tax ID 
$street = $user_street; //'Rua Moraes e Silva'; //endereço do sacado – buyer’s street address 
$number = $user_number; //'98'; //número do endereço do sacado – buyer’s house number 
$complement = $user_complement; //'Apartamento 404'; //complemento do endereço do sacado – buyer’s address complement 
$district = $user_district; //'Tijuca'; //bairro do sacado – buyer’s neighborhood 
$state_province = $user_state; //RJ'; //estado do sacado – buyer’s state 
$city = $user_city; //'Rio de Janeiro'; //cidade do sacado – buyer’s city 
$postcode = $user_postcode; //'20271-030'; //CEP do sacado – buyer’s ZIP code 
$country = $user_country; //073; //país do sacado – buyer’s country 
$value = $user_value; //100.00; //valor do boleto – amount 
$product = 'Produto 1'; // Nome do produto
$url_return = ''; // URL de retorno 

// $URL = "http://boleto.msbbank.com.br/boleto.php"; 
// $n_website = '20468565324-1'; //identificador único adquirido para acesso ao sistema – unique website ID 
// $password = '1e$ha!.'; //senha adquirida para acesso ao sistema - password 
// $uid = uniqid(); //identificador único da transação no website – unique transaction ID 
// $name = 'Daniel Rodrigues'; //nome do sacado – buyer’s name 
// $identificador = '11091866732'; //CPF do sacado – buyer’s tax ID 
// $street = 'Rua Moraes e Silva'; //endereço do sacado – buyer’s street address 
// $number = '98'; //número do endereço do sacado – buyer’s house number 
// $complement =  'Apartamento 404'; //complemento do endereço do sacado – buyer’s address complement 
// $district = 'Tijuca'; //bairro do sacado – buyer’s neighborhood 
// $state_province = 'RJ'; //estado do sacado – buyer’s state 
// $city = 'Rio de Janeiro'; //cidade do sacado – buyer’s city 
// $postcode = '20271-030'; //CEP do sacado – buyer’s ZIP code 
// $country = 073; //país do sacado – buyer’s country 
// $value = 100.00; //valor do boleto – amount 
// $product = 'Produto 1'; // Nome do produto
// $url_return = ''; // URL de retorno 
$xml = "<requisicao-boleto>
                <website>
                    <n_website>{$n_website}</n_website>
                    <password>{$password}</password>
                </website>

                <sacado>
                    <name>{$name}</name>
                    {$user_code}
                    <address>
                        <street>{$street}</street>
                        <complement>{$complement}</complement>
                        <number>{$number}</number>
                        <district>{$district}</district>
                        <state_province>{$state_province}</state_province>
                        <city>{$city}</city>
                        <postcode>{$postcode}</postcode>
                        <country>{$country}</country>
                    </address>
                </sacado>
                <dados_boleto>
                    <product>{$product}</product>
                    <reference>{$uid}</reference>
                    <value>{$value}</value>
                </dados_boleto>
            </requisicao-boleto>";

    $xml = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $xml);
    $xml = "xml=" . $xml;

    $n = strlen($xml);

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "POST",
            'header' => "User-Agent: My Own Http Client\r\n" .
                "Content-length: " . $n . "\r\n",
            'content' => $xml
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $handle = fopen($URL, 'r', false, $context);

    $conteudo = '';

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $conteudo .= fread($handle, 1024);
    }

    $content = (string)$conteudo;

    fclose($handle);

    $local = fopen($brazpay."/boletos/".$uid.".htm", "w+");
    fwrite($local, $content);
    fclose($local);
    print $uid;
}

if (isset($_GET['validate'])) {
  $fid = $_GET['usid'];
  $path = $brazpay."/boletos/$fid.htm";

  $o = fopen($path,"r");
  $boleto_html = fread($o, filesize($path));
  fclose($o);

  $admin_email = get_option("admin_email");
  $currentuser = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_email = $currentuser->user_email;

  $to = "$user_email";
  $subject = "BOLETO - Brazpay";

  $message = $boleto_html;

  // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

  // More headers
  $headers .= 'From: <system@brazpay.com>' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Bcc: $admin_email' . "\r\n";

  $error = @mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 

  print $error;

  print"email sent to $user_email and $admin_email"; 

} 

?>
```

Comment: Where do you open the file and give `$handle` a resource i.e. where is the `fopen()`

Comment: I suppose the good news is that you are actually looking at your PHP error log occasionally

Comment: Hi, I am adding more code up there...

Comment: And now `$context` is missing

Comment: It might also be a GOOD IDEA to test `if ($handle === false) { echo 'bugger';}`

Comment: I have added this full block of code...

Comment: Here we go again `$opts` is now missing!

Comment: ahahaha... I guess I will add full code here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [file_get_contents](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? Instead of

```
$handle = fopen($URL, 'r', false, $context);
$conteudo = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $conteudo .= fread($handle, 1024);
}
$content = (string)$conteudo;
fclose($handle);
```

it could be simply

```
$content = (string) file_get_contents($URL, false, $context);
```

You could have even more control over the HTTP exchange by using [cURL](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of file access functions.

Comment: Thanks! I had to make a few changes to the server as well, as "allow_url_fopen" was disabled. But your solution fixed my main issue! :)